# Windows 10 won't boot after moving EFI partition

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, uefi, efi

On dualboot, I had two EFI partitions on two drives.
One drive with EFI partition for GNU/Linux, second drive and EFI partition for Windows.

I moved Windows boot files from second EFI partition to first one.

Then, I deleted the second EFI partition.
Windows starts booting, and ends up in BSOD.

> Error: IO1 INITIALIZATION FAILED

I tried to "recover boot" from Windows installation media but it does not make it boot correctly.

What else can I do besides reinstalling?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created the EFI partition on the same drive it was before and moved the Windows EFI files there, it boots again.

I will stick to multiple EFI partitions and chainloading.

Comment: Oops, here I am with the same issue, except this time it's because I removed an unused recovery partition before the EFI partition. My *guess* is that something addresses the drives by "nth partition on nth disk" -- if it was addressed by GUID, re-creating would not work. Unfortunately for me even rebuilding BCD with `bcdboot` isn't working, probably something to do with the partition I stupidly deleted...